# Editing start vertex of multiple elements synchronously using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, topology, vertices

I have 20 or so sight line elements (2-vertex lines) which have their start vertex at a single point - a point element in another layer.

If I move that start point, how can I move all 20 concurrent start vertices with it, leaving the end vertices in the their original place?

I am using QGIS 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by enabling the editing of all line layers, enabling the `Vertex tool (all layers)`, and on Snapping toolbar, click `Enable Topological Editing`.

Here is a screenshot of what you need to enable:

[image]

Then you will be able to click on the vertex of shared points and move them at once to a new location:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

**Update**

If all the lines are located in the same layer, you need only to `Enable Topological Editing`. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: But does this work if all the sightlines are in the same layer?  Topological Editing I believe only works between layers.

Comment: @user3808985 Yes it works if all lines are located in the same layer. You need to enable the topological editing. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for showing where the "Enable Topological Editing" tool is - it is not in Settings > Options > Digitising > Snapping.  With that tool set the multi-element vertex edit does work as we would like it to.

Comment: @user3808985 You are welcome. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a tool to edit multiple features' vertices at once. As a workaround you can create a new line layer which starts from the moved point.

[Tool] **Geometry by expression** (in `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`)

[Settings]

- Input layer: your line layer
- Output geometry type: Line

[Expression]

```
 make_line(geometry (get_feature_by_id('point', 1)), end_point($geometry))
```

where your point layer name is `point`.

[image]

Comment: This does look like a neat way to do what I want.  It creates a new temporary layer with the same number of elements as the source sightline layer.  However, the geometry of the new elements is all NULL.  Building from your idea I also tried get_feature() to get the geometry by attribute, with the same result.  The log does not show an error.

Comment: @user3808985 One possibility is that your point layername is not `point`. Another possibility, the point id is not 1. Or something else. Your dataset information would be helpful.

Comment: I ran your suggestion in a new environment where the table names had no spaces or underscores and it works, thank you.  So it seems that there is a problem with the "Geometry by Expression" tool passing the right names to the underlying tool.  Both sets of data are in GPKG databases.

Comment: @user3808985 I'm glad it worked out. As to the spaces and underscores in the layer name, I could not reproduce the issue with my QGIS 3.8.0 / 3.4.9. But it was just a quick test (simply changing `point` to `point x`), so it may not be a proper test. You may want to file a bug report.

Comment: I am torn between the two presented solutions! amandhanb's solution is all GUI and directly answers the question as I put it.  But your answer shows a glimpse of QGIS' gleaming underlying engine and actually produces a better result for me because it makes a temporary layer I can slice and dice with.  Forgive me for selecting the other answer as the most appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: @user3808985 Yes, you did make a good and suitable choice. I always learn new things from ahmadhanb.